# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' when requesting class based view Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

Hi this should be an easy one i'm sure. Just losing my patience with class based views. Not really sure how they simplify things. Function based views seem to a lot more readable and make more sense. Anyway am trying to convert one of my functional views to a class one and getting this error when I request the view

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

PS I am using django 1.8.1 and the way I import View is through django.views.generic.View not django.views.View as described in the docs. Might be relevant.

Here is the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload_photo/$', views.upload_photo, name='upload_photo'),
    url(r'^upload_photo_class/$', views.UploadPhotoView.as_view()),
    ]
```

Here is the class based view

```
class UploadPhotoView(View):
    form = PhotoModelForm
    formset = formset_factory(PhotoExtendedModelForm, max_num=1, validate_min=True)
    template_name = 'upload_photo.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form
        formset = self.formset
        return (request, self.template_name, {'form': form,
                                          'formset': formset})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        formset = self.formset(request.POST)
        if all([form.is_valid(), formset.is_valid()]):

            photo = form.save()
            photo_instance = photo
            user_id = request.user

            for inline_form in formset:

                data = inline_form.save(commit=False)
                data.Photo = photo_instance
                data.user = user_id
                data.save()

            return render(request, 'upload_photo_done.html')

        else:
            return (request, self.template_name, {'form': form,
                                              'formset': formset})
```

Here is the original function based view

```
@login_required
def upload_photo(request):
    form = PhotoModelForm
    formset = formset_factory(PhotoExtendedModelForm, max_num=1, validate_min=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = form(request.POST, request.FILES)
         formset = formset(request.POST)
         if all([form.is_valid(), formset.is_valid()]):

            photo = form.save()
            photo_instance = photo
            user_id = request.user

            for inline_form in formset:

                data = inline_form.save(commit=False)
                data.Photo = photo_instance
                data.user = user_id
                data.save()

            return render(request, 'upload_photo_done.html')

        else:
            return render(request, 'upload_photo.html', {'form': form, 'formset': formset})
    else:
        return render(request, 'upload_photo.html', {'form': form, 'formset': formset})
```

Heres the traceback:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/otologue/upload_photo_class/

Django Version: 1.8.1
Python Version: 3.4.4
Installed Applications:
('account',
 'photologue_custom',
 'otologue',
 'photologue',
 'sortedm2m',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  223.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py" in process_response
  31.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /otologue/upload_photo_class/
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the def get(), you are supposed to return an **HttpResponse** object like this

```
     HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
```

OR use render() to redirect to template. You are trying to return a plain tuple with render function call parameters.

Comment: Hi thanks that worked! I have also done the same for the post() else: part and put a render there as well.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept this as the answer, so others will get clear idea when they come across a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to inherit from `FormView` rather than just `view`. So your first line will be `class UploadPhotoView(FormView):`

It will simplify a lot of your form handling and boilerplate, which is a lot of the benefit of class based views. As usual, the [Django documentation on this is](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) great.

In your case it *might* be as simple as:

```
class UploadPhotoView(FormView):
    form_class = PhotoModelForm
    template_name = 'upload_photo.html'
    success_url = '/upload-done/' # set url to TemplateView.as_view(template_name="upload_photo_done.html")

 def form_valid(self, form):
     # do the stuff in your POST method
     return super(UploadPhotoView, self).form_valid(form)`
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice, I have tried to implement the changes but doing that gives errors on the 'request' functions. As I understand the form_valid will get the POST information will it also get the FILES as well? And to determine the user_id how would that work in a FormView

Comment: I believe the files should be in `form.cleaned_data['your_upload_name']` or in `self.request.FILES['your_upload_name']`.